# How do GIMP avoid color blocks when increase/decrease Saturation

Tags: image-processing, gimp

Take https://subtilitas.org/hsv/indexEn.htm for example

It is clearly that color blocks will happen when increase/decrease saturation. But how do GIMP do the similar work? It will produce images without blocks. A post Gaussian filter? I'm not sure and quite curious about this.

Comment: What do you mean by `color blocks`?

Comment: @Astor, when increasing saturation, the sky in the image will have significant boundary for discontinuous colors.